# What dose this macro,"__CV_BEGIN__",mean in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, macros

Recently,I'm reading some source code in OpenCV. I find this macro,"**CV_BEGIN**",and I don't know what it means. So I trace its declaration. Finally i found it and somthing other like that in the header file,"internal.hpp":

```
#define __BEGIN__ __CV_BEGIN__
#define __END__ __CV_END__
#define EXIT __CV_EXIT__
```

If anybody know that, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's some pretty strange legacy construct. Here's the definitions from core_c.h

```
#define __CV_BEGIN__       {
#define __CV_END__         goto exit; exit: ; }
#define __CV_EXIT__        goto exit
```

So, those look like some means to make C code look like Pascal code. Can't actually tell, why you'd want such a thing.

Comment: You can find an example of usage in some old doco: http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/c/core_utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html. Seems to be just some awful coding std that someone was using.  `goto exit; exit: ;` is pretty weird..